# General questions about JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

In my app I need to update user location by [Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java) every 15 minutes continiously,but I am confused with some parameters.Currently I have

```
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(AppConstants.USER_DATA_UPDATE_JOB_ID, new ComponentName(getActivity().getPackageName(), UserDataUpdateScheduler.class.getName()));
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
        builder.setPeriodic(900000);
        builder.setPersisted(true);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

What exactly indicates jobScheduler to start job again  `builder.setPeriodic(900000);`  or  `jobFinished(params, true);` ? And also can't understand the meanings of `onStartJob` and `onStopJob` return values.

Also an additional question,in Android O a background service cannot receive location updates more than a few times per hour.So approxiamtely how much is that few times?

Answer (score 1):

```
setPeriodic(long intervalMillis)
```

Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval, not more than once per period.In others words, this job must repeat with the interval assigned, in milis, 9000 = 9 seconds.

```
JobFinished
```

Call this to inform the JobScheduler that the job has finished its work. When the system receives this message, it releases the wakelock being held for the job.

Comment: Thx for the answer,so if my job was done successfully I don't need to pass `true` for `jobFinished` second parameter right?

Comment: And can you please tell me for my task do I need to return true or false in onStartJob?

Answer (score 0):

```
setPeriodic(long intervalMillis)
```

Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval, not more than once per period the MinimumInterval for this method is 15 minutes or 900000 milliseconds
And

`JobFinished`

call when your job is Finished

(if your task is short write on onStart method and return false without calling JobFinished method )

note: if you define Your Job Periodic in jobFinished always return false